# InnoDB - IBD file growing to eat all of the space on the server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mariadb, innodb

**The Environment**

We have a staging/test WordPress site on a CentOS server running MariaDB (version 10.3.8).  We've been experimenting with a plugin called GeoDirectory (https://wpgeodirectory.com/) The plugin creates a variety of tables in the database.  The database also is using the `innodb_file_per_table` set to ON, so the database has generated IBD files for each tablespace in the database.

**The Issue**

The staging server had 80 GB of storage.  After making a particular change to the settings of the plugin (updating the Place Settings), we noticed that about ten minutes later the staging site was timing out when we tried to access it via the browser.

Logging in via SSH, we noticed that the machine was completely out of space.  Looking for the largest files in /var, I noticed that *one* file was now taking up 70 GB of space (`wp_g1a4rar7xx_geodir_gd_place_detail.ibd`).  This is the IBD file that corresponded to the table where the settings were updated.

Logging into SQL and running a count(*) on the number of records in that table, there were only 6,000 records.

Because the table had blown up to take up the entirety of the disk, even trying `OPTIMIZE TABLE` wouldn't work because of the lack of space.

**The Question**

What could have happened to make that file balloon so large so quickly?  How can we avoid this happening in the future?

**Reckless Speculation**

Based on searches, we believe it might have something to do with the rollback/logging that InnoDB performs, and that we might be able to avoid this by making some changes in `my.cnf` to limiting logging.  Again, it could be something completely different.

Here's the current `my.cnf` from `/etc/my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
# bind-address = ::ffff:127.0.0.1
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security 
risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mariadb according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log
pid-file=/var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: 6000 rows can take 70GB if each row stores 12MB of data. Run `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'wp_g1a4rar7xx_geodir_gd_place_detail'\G` and check the Data_length, Index_length, and Avg_row_length. Also the Data_free might be indicative of fragmentation in the tablespace.

Comment: The SHOW TABLE STATUS statement is something you'd run in the mysql client (where you have the `mysql>` prompt). I shouldn't assume you're familiar with that statement.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE TABLE` should work _if_ there is enough room for the _new_ copy of the table in the free disk space.  (Yeah, that seems unlikely.)  The `SHOW` should say whether this might be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the name of the plugin, I am guessing that the issue could be related to updates of indexed geometry columns. MariaDB Server 10.2 imported the InnoDB support for SPATIAL INDEX from MySQL 5.7, and it looks like the purge of version history is sometimes being skipped, depending on concurrent DML activity.

I have mentioned this peculiar design choice in [MDEV-15284](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-15284), which reports that SELECT on a SPATIAL INDEX can return inconsistent results if a concurrent ROLLBACK is being executed.